# How to get table one removed ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a resource called `User`, and it `has_many` `Session`s. A `Session` `has_many` `Items`. I'm using Rails and need an ActiveRecord call to list all the `Item`s that a user has. How would I do that? I don't know how to fetch all the indirectly associated records (not sure what's the right term).

Answer (score 1):

other alternative, if you already set user model with has_many sessions 
then you can add has_many through with sample code below
and each user can access items

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sessions
  has_many :items, through: :sessions
  # this additional settings so user dan access items directly
end

@user = User.first
@items = @user.items
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- `Item` belongs to `Session`
- `Item` has `session_id`
- You have an instance of `User` called `@user`

Then try:

```
Item.where(session: @user.sessions)
```